# I want to filter a datatable, but I'm not able to do that

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I want to filter a data table on the basis of given string, But I'm not able to that. 
Here is the View Code :-

```
<div ng-if="pageScope.tableViewLoad" class="well innerN">
                    <div class="fl" style="height:40px; width:30px;"></div>
                    <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumnDefs" dt-instance="showRolodexTable" class=" table table-striped table-hover  border-top-bottom  wdth-frst-rolodex fixed-table rolodextable tr-cell" width="100%" style="min-width:1013px">
                        <thead>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <!-- <tr ng-repeat="user in ulList | rolodexFilter:searchRolodex:searchCriteria:categoryMap" on-finish-render="ngRepeatRolodex" class="test" ng-click="testdemo()"> -->
                            <tr ng-repeat="user in ulList | rolodexFilter:searchRolodex:searchCriteria:categoryMap track by $index" on-finish-render="ngRepeatRolodex" class="test">
```

And here is the controller code :-

```
$scope.searchDataTableUsers=function(){
     localStorage.setItem("namecopy",$scope.searchRolodex);
         if(name1!=null)
         {
            $scope.searchRolodex=name1;
            name1=null;
         }
    if(!$scope.searchRolodex==null){
                   var newUlList = $scope.ulList.filter(function(ulList){
                       return ulList.$filter('$scope.searchRolodex');
                   });
                   console.log("Pawan New list |",newUlList);
               }
    if($scope.oTableRolodex && $scope.searchRolodex && $scope.searchRolodex.trim().length > 0)
    $scope.oTableRolodex.DataTable.search($scope.searchRolodex).draw();
}

$scope.showRolodexTable = function(dtInstance) {
    $scope.oTableRolodex = dtInstance;
    $scope.searchDataTableUsers();
}

$scope.$watch('searchRolodex', function (newValue, oldValue) {
   localStorage.removeItem("namecopy");

  $scope.searchDataTableUsers();

});
```

I hope, someone will help in this regard.

PS : Thanks in advance.

PPS: Anybody is here to help.?

Comment: You could start by defining `name1` ...

Comment: defining name1 to what.? I did't get your view. Please explain a bit more. Because I'm new in angular.

And if, possible, please adda fiddle example here to get some idea for it.

Comment: `name1` from your code above `if(name1!=null)` ...

Comment: I have tried that, but no luck. I need to search the list on the basis of given string and rerender the datatable to show all the columns.
But, when I apply the changes, it breaks the pagination of the table.

Comment: I tried to filter the list by custom filter, it comes with the result data, but breaks the pagination of the table And when I try to navigate, it shows no data at all.